# How to do "negative" match in Ltac?

Tags: coq, ltac

I want to apply a rule in a case when some hypothesis present, and another is not. How can I check for this condition?

For example:

```coq
Variable X Y : Prop.
Axiom A: X -> Y.
Axiom B: X -> Z.

Ltac more_detail :=
    match goal with
     |[H1:X,<not H2:Y>|-_]  =>
      let H' := fresh "DET" in assert Y as H'
                                   by (apply A;assumption)
     |[H1:X,<not H2:Z>|-_]  =>
      let H' := fresh "DET" in assert Z as H'
                                   by (apply B;assumption)
    end.
```

Such that, for this goal:

```coq
> Goal X->True. intros.

H:X
=====
True
```

`more_detail.` would introduce a second hypothesis DET:

```
H:X
DET:Y
DET0:Z
=====
True
```

And a successive invocation `more_detail.` would fail.

However `more_detail.` should always ensure, that both `Y` and `Z` are there, i.e. if only one of them present, it should run a rule for another:

```coq
Goal X->Y->True. intros.

H:X
H1:Y
=====
True

> more_detail.

H:X
H1:Y
DET:Z
=====
True
```

And:

```coq
> Goal X->Z->True. intros.

H:X
H0:Z
=====
True

> more_detail.

H:X
H0:Z
DET:Y
=====
True
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common Ltac pattern. You can use the `fail` tactic to avoid executing a branch when some condition matches:

```coq
Variable X Y Z : Prop.
Hypothesis A : X -> Y.
Hypothesis B : X -> Z.

Ltac does_not_have Z :=
  match goal with
  | _ : Z |- _ => fail 1
  | |- _ => idtac
  end.

Ltac more_detail :=
  match goal with
  | H : X |- _ =>
    first [ does_not_have Y;
            let DET := fresh "DET" in
            assert (DET := A H)
          | does_not_have Z;
            let DET := fresh "DET" in
            assert (DET := B H) ]
  end.

Goal X -> True.
intros X. more_detail. more_detail.
(* This fails *)
more_detail.
Abort.
```

The `does_not_have` tactic acts as a negative match: it only succeeds if its argument is not present in the context. Here's how it works: if `H : Z` is present in the context, the first branch will match. Calling  simply `fail` or `fail 0` would cause that branch to fail, but would allow Ltac to try other branches of the same `match`. Using `fail 1` causes the current branch *and* the entire match to fail. If `H : Z` is not present in the context, the first branch will never match, and Coq will skip it and try the second branch. Since this branch doesn't do anything, execution will proceed with whichever tactics come after the `match`.

In `more_detail`, the `first` tactical can be used to combine several invocations of `does_not_have`; since each branch of `first` will fail if the context contains the corresponding hypothesis, the construction as a whole will have the effect of your `match` with negative patterns.

Comment: Wow, that's cool! But It wouldn't work if I have two such cases in the same match, because the first would fail on a "negative match", and the second will be never tried

Comment: @Necto I think I understood what you mean, but could you please update your question with an example illustrating what you just said? I'm pretty sure it can be done.

Comment: I've expanded the question, as you asked

Comment: @Necto just expanded the answer to include the case you asked about.